# A vector space V has finite dimension only and only if every linear application is annihilated by a polynomial non

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a $K$-vector space, given a linear trasformation $T:V\rightarrow V$ define $Z_T=\{f\in K[X]|f(T)=0\}$. Then $Z_T\neq\{0\}$ for all $T:V\rightarrow V$ iff $V$ is finite dimensional.

One direction is easily solved using Cayley-Hamilton Theorem.

To the other direction, I was trying to use the counterpositive, if $Z_T=\{0\}$ for some $T$, then V is infinite dimensional, but I can't find the solution.

Comment: Are you allowed to assume every vector space has a basis?

Comment: Hint: All you need is provide a linear transformation with infinitely many eigenvalues in each infinite-dimensional $V$. Polynomials will fail to eliminate infinitely many eigenspaces.

Comment: @TheoBendit's suggestion will only work if $K$ is an infinite field.  For an example that works for finite fields as well, choose some countable linearly independent subset $(x_0, x_1, x_2, \ldots) \subseteq V$ and then construct a linear transformation such that $T(x_n) = x_{n+1}$.

Comment: Your "other direction" is equivalent to the easy direction. What you want instead is to show that if V is infinite dimensional, there exists a transformation that has trivial $Z_T$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $V$ be an infinite dimensional vector space.
By Zorn's lemma there exist a basis of $V$. Call that basis set $B$.

Take a countable subset of $B$. Call it $B'$.

$B'=\{v_1,v_2,v_3 \dots \}$

Define a transformation

$T(v_i)=v_{i+1}$ for all $v_i \in B'$

And $T(v)=v$ for any element belonging to $B\setminus B'$.

This defines a transformation from $V$ to $V$ as I have defined it for all the basis elements.

Now take any $f\in k[X]$, $f\neq 0$ then $f(v_1)\neq 0$ as then a linear combination with non-zero coefficients of a linear combination of linearly independent vectors will be $0$. Hence the other side of the problem is solved.